# Combine data from several tables mysql

Tags: mysql

I need help on the construction of a query to mysql database ... I have two tables - products and productStatus

**Products**

```
id, productName
1, Orange
2, Apple
3, Lemon
4, Cherry
```

**ProductStatus**

```
id, productId, status, date
1, 1, 1, 2022-07-11 07:00:00
2, 1, 3, 2022-07-11 08:00:00
3, 1, 5, 2022-07-11 09:00:00
4, 3, 1, 2022-07-11 07:00:00
```

Product statuses are added every few hours. I need to use mysql query to list products only where recently added status (ORDER BY date DESC) equals 1 or this productId is not in productStatus table.

I am currently doing this in 2 queries in a while loop (almost like below) but I need to optimize it to one query. Is it possible?

```
$queryProduct = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM Products");
while ($queryProductR = mysqli_fetch_array($queryProduct)) {
 
 $productStatus = false;
 
 $queryStatus = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM ProductStatus WHERE productId=".$queryProductR[id]." ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1");
 $queryStatusR = mysqli_fetch_array($queryStatus);
 
 if($queryStatusR[status]==1) {
  $productStatus = true;
 }
 else if($queryStatusR[status]==null){
  $productStatus = true;
 }
 else {
  $productStatus = false;
 }
 
 if($productStatus) {
  // show product 
 }
}
```

Comment: What is precise MySQL version?

Comment: Look into using [sql joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/), specifically [MySQL's JOIN clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html).

Comment: The question about 'version' is important because 8.0 includes "windowing functions", which may be needed.

Comment: current version: 10.4.24-MariaDB-cll-lve

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved :)

```
SELECT * FROM Products LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM ProductStatus WHERE status=1 GROUP BY date desc) as ProductStatusB ON Products.id=ProductStatusB.productId Group by Products.id
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).